# PHP namespaces, class not found

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I have a Laravel 5 project, which uses several libraries using composer.

I want one library to be a part of the project, so I removed it from composer, copied the files from Vendor to the Project directory, but after moving the files from Vendor to Project Directory, I get an error that dgr\nohup\Nohup is not found.

The autoload of one of the library looks like this

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "dgr\\nohup\\": "src/"
    }
 }
```

which allowed me to import

```
<?php
    use dgr\nohup\Nohup;
    use dgr\nohup\Process;

class MyClass

}
```

Comment: Did you run `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: Yes I did run composer dumpautoload.

Comment: That is because you didn't specify your class `namespace`

Comment: Where should I do that? An example would be great.

Answer (score -1):

namespace

```
App\Http\Controllers;
```